# Change in Address URL, issue in Search Form result redirection

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, search-form

I have developed a website in wordpress. I have changed the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in the settings->general page in admin area.

My issue is that when I search something through the "search form", the search goes to domain.com/?something (strange page destructured) but the right link would be [www.domain.com/?something](http://www.domain.com/?something).

How can I correct that?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possible causes.

1. WordPress might be using cached values for its permalinks.  Try going to Settings .. Permalinks and click "Save Changes" to rebuild the list.
2. Check you don't have a redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com in your `.htaccess` file
3. The old domain could be stored somewhere in the database (I think that's more likely in post content than a search URL, but I can't rule it out).  In that case, I'd recommend using the "Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" mentioned in the [Moving WordPress Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change).  In your case, you'd replace `http://domain.com` with `http://www.domain.com` **after doing a database backup** (as replacing `domain.com` with `www.domain.com` would result in `www.www.domain.com` for values you've already updated).